# MS ACCESS GROUP BY doesnt return anything

Tags: database, ms-access

Why does my SQL code not return a result even if the condition is true?

Here's my SQL code:

```
SELECT DateOfPurchased AS [Date], 
       COUNT(TransactionID) AS [Total transaction], 
       COUNT(CustomerID) AS [Number of Customers], 
       SUM(Quantity) AS [Total Quantity], 
       SUM(Books.Price * Transactions.Quantity) AS [Sum Of Sales]
FROM Transactions INNER JOIN Books ON Books.BookID = Transactions.BookID
WHERE DateOfPurchased = #04/10/2017#
GROUP BY DateOfPurchased
```

Comment: Is your date in MM/DD format? It is the default format in MS access (not DD/MM). So there your are searching for records of 10th of April and not 04th of October

Comment: I'm not sure if this has an affect, so someone feel free to correct me if I'm wrong, but shouldn't `ON Books.BookID = Transactions.BookID` be `ON Transactions.BookID = Books.BookID` - does the order here matter?

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook that's entirely irrelevant, as far as I know

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth  It was something I'd never considered - I've always written them in the same order as they appear and I couldn't remember if it was something specific I'd been told on one of the courses I've been on or just because that's the way I've always done it.  Just ran a quick test and you're right - didn't make a bit of difference to the resulting table.

Answer (score 0):

Are you storing the dates as general date and thus including the time as well?  That was the only way I could replicate your issue.

Comment: This is not an answer.

Comment: I can't comment on other peoples posts because of my low reputation score.  Just trying to help the guy out since he didn't respond to any of the comments on his post.